# android BookShelf issue downloading quaere library

Tags: android

I found a bookshelf project on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389071/Create-a-dynamic-shelfview-in-Android.

I downloaded the code and built the code but issue with the libs so i tried downloading the libs and referencing from the project, But i couldn't find the quaere.jar on the net.

In the project he mention a link (http://quaere.codehaus.org/) but i dint find the jar.

Please help me where exactly can i download the jar.

Comment: i am facing same issue like you ,did you solved this@Chanu Sukarno